# How do i echo the items selected in this query?

Tags: php, sql

i'm a beginner in php.Can someone help me with getting the output of the query below ?And is there any problem with my code that i'm not getting the right output.I got this Resource id #3 as output and at the bottom bar it says "error on page"

```
$question_text = $_POST['question_text'];

list($first_word) = explode(' ', $question_text);

$query ="SELECT c.field_name,t.category_name, d.domain_name FROM category_fields c, taxonomy_category t, taxonomy_domain d WHERE c.category_Id = t.category_Id AND t.domain_Id = d.domain_Id AND c.field_name = '".mysql_escape_string($first_word[0])."'";
```

I want to get the field_name,category_name and domain_name from different tables where the id's of them match as in the query,thanks in adv!

Comment: Read the chapter in your PHP book (or in the PHP documentation) about working with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should be using [PDO and prepared queries](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) to secure your application.  At least use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).  As it stands right now, you can be subjected to SQL injection attacks.

Second, you can't just output the query result resource.  You need to do something like mysql_fetch_assoc() and output its result.

```
 $qStuff=mysql_query(YOUR_QUERY_GOES_HERE);
 while ($results=mysql_fetch_assoc($qStuff)) {
      print_r($results);
 }
```

Again though, use PDO instead.  There is a great tutorial on the above link.